# copy file with different names in current directory shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, cp

My bash script

```
echo -n "Round Name:"
read round
mkdir $round

echo -n "File Names:"
read $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6
cp ~/Documents/Library/Template.py $1.py $2.py $3.py $4.py $5.py $6.py .
```

I have automation for directories and want the same automation for filenames.

After taking unknown inputs, How can I make my shell scripts do this? 
`cp ~/Documents/Library/Template.py A.py B.py C.py D1.py D2.py $round/.`

Comment: Question not clear: "it will do this … how do I do it?" — Do what? "Tried this" — did it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than reading the various strings interactively, just have the user pass them on the script's command line.

The following script would be called like

```bsh
./script -d dirname -t templatefile -- string1 string2 string3 string4
```

... and it would create `dirname` if it doesn't already exist, and then copy `templatefile` into that directory with the root names given by the strings.  If the template file has a filename suffix, this would be added to the end of each string to create the new filenames (after removing the suffix from the string as to not duplicate an already existing suffix).

You may bypass the step in the script that creates the directory by using the `-n` option, which makes the script assume that the directory specified by `-d` already exists.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# Unset strings set via options.
unset -v dirpath do_mkdir templatepath

# Do command line parsing for -d and -t options.
while getopts d:nt: opt; do
    case $opt in
        d)
            dirpath=$OPTARG
            ;;
        n)
            do_mkdir=false
            ;;
        t)
            templatepath=$OPTARG
            ;;
        *)
            echo 'Error in command line parsing' >&2
            exit 1
    esac
done

shift "$((OPTIND - 1))"

# Sanity checks.
: "${dirpath:?Missing directory path (-d)}"
: "${templatepath:?Missing template file path (-t)}"

if [ ! -f "$templatepath" ]; then
    printf 'Can not find template file "%s"\n' "$templatepath" >&2
    exit 1
fi

if "${do_mkdir-true}"; then
    # Create destination directory.
    mkdir -p -- "$dirpath" || exit
fi
if [ ! -d "$dirpath" ]; then
    printf 'Directory "%s" does not exist\n' "$dirpath" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# Check to see whether the template file has a filename suffix.
# If so, save the suffix in $suffix.
suffix=${templatepath##*.}
if [ "$suffix" = "$templatepath" ]; then
    # No filename suffix.
    suffix=''
else
    # Has filename suffix.
    suffix=.$suffix
fi

# Do copying.
for string do
    # Remove the suffix from the string,
    # if the string ends with the suffix.
    string=${string%$suffix}
    cp -- "$templatepath" "$dirpath/$string$suffix"
done
```

To recreate your example at the end of your question, you would use this script like so:

```bsh
./script -t ~/Documents/Library/Template.py -d "$round" -- A B C D1 D2
```

Comment: Does this mean i have to write `cf -t ~/Documents/Library/Template.py -d "contest" -- A B C D1 D2` everytime if i have this script named `cf` in `export PATH=$PATH:~/scripts/`?

Comment: @MegaBang If that is the arguments that you want to run the script with, yes. You don't have to `export` the `PATH` variable though, as it's already exported.  Using command line options and other arguments is usually easier than passing data to a script via `read`.

Comment: Can you refactor this code to skip folder making and just create the files?

Comment: @MegaBang If the destination directory already exists, there will be no error. You still need to tell the script where the destination directory exists with `-d` though, or we wouldn't know where the files should be copied to.

Comment: what if i don't want to make folder? Could you please help me add this option?

Comment: @MegaBang Comment out the `mkdir` command. I'm not modifying the code in my answer as you definitely wanted to make a directory in your question.

Comment: Ah.. i meant in that single script what can we do to skip folder making process?

Comment: @MegaBang See update answer. I will not touch this further as it's neither upvoted nor accepted.

Comment: `./script -t ~/Documents/Library/Template.py -n contest -- A B C D1 D2` doesn't work. What will be the correct approach?

Comment: @MegaBang `-n` does not take an argument, you would still use `-d` to specify the already existing directory, so `./script -n -t ~/Documents/Library/Template.py -d contest -- A B C D1 D2`.  The only thing different with `-n` is that `mkdir` will not be called and that the script will terminate with a fatal error if the directory specified with `-d` does not exist.

Comment: last thing. Can you modify the code? if i even write `-- A.py B.py` i will get the same result

Comment: I'm trying to add the last feature in another script. where `A B.py C D.py` turns to `A.py B.py C.py D.py` . Would you be kind enough to code simple one? Does this mean `$string$suffix` filename with extension?

Comment: @MegaBang No, because I don't know what you want. I thought your last comment asked for adding a suffix to the given strings only if there was no suffix already on them. With your latest comment I'm no longer sure what you want. I also have a job to do.

Comment: sorry to disturb you. here's my another thread (what i want) https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/686183/508426

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Round Name:"
read round
mkdir $round

read -r -p "Enter the filenames:" -a arr
for filenames in "${arr[@]}"; do 
cp ~/Documents/Library/Template.py $round/$filenames
done
```

This is done with an array, so it accepts infinite inputs. Just input the filenames separated by space, like so:

```
Enter the filenames:test1 test2 test3
```

Comment: I want to go to that directory. Could you please help me implement `cd $round` in this code?

Comment: You can add `cd $round` below `mkdir $round` without the && and remove the `$round` variable when doing `cp` in the loop

Comment: @MegaBang Note that no script could change the directory for the session that _invokes_ the script. Changing the directory for the script is in this case not necessary.

Comment: @Alex As an alternative to your loop: `tee "${arr[@]/#/$round/}" >/dev/null <~/Documents/Library/Template.py`