# turn `A B.py C D.py` to `A.py B.py C.py D.py` detecting from file extension in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, files

related to [this thread answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/685150/508426) 
if the input is `A B.py C D.py`, the output turns into `A.py B.py C.py D.py`

I want to implement this feature in another script given below:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Round Name:"
read round
mkdir $round

read -r -p "Enter the filenames:" -a arr
for filenames in "${arr[@]}"; do 
cp ~/Documents/Library/Template.py $round/$filenames
done
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Where does `$FileExt` come from?

Comment: file extension i guess. I'm a noob at shell script

Comment: That's probably its meaning, but my question is how the variable is supposed to get a value, since it's not set in the script.

Comment: don't know that :(

Comment: "_tried this but didn't work_" - What happened? What didn't happen that you expected to happen? What error messages did you get? Please remember that we are not sitting on your shoulder so you have to be precise in your description of a problem. Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/686183/edit) to replace or expand on that sentence with detail.

Comment: @roaima done.. plz check

Comment: How should the script know that it needs to turn `A` into `A.py` and `C` into `C.py`? Is it simply a case of adding `.py` if there isn't already a `.py` on the end (so that either `A` or `A.py` are mapped to the same `A.py`)?

Comment: it will automatically take input from the respective file extensions

Comment: `A` doesn't have a file extension. Where does it come from?

Comment: mainly the theme is if i write or don't write the extension name in input like `A B.py`, the output will be automatically converted to `A.py B.py`  ....

from predefined template files, via input `A` script will detect `.py` or respective file extensions

Comment: Please add that vital information to your question. Also while you're there, explain what you mean by these "predefined template files". Like I said [back in January](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/686183/turn-a-b-py-c-d-py-to-a-py-b-py-c-py-d-py-detecting-from-file-extension-in-s#comment1297667_686183), remember that we are not sitting on your shoulder so you have to be precise in your description of a problem. So far it's anything but precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that what you want to do is to add a `.py` suffix to each argument unless there's one already present.

You can do this for a simple variable as in this example code

```
for item in A A.py
do
    dest=${item%.py}.py
    echo "Demonstrating that '$item' becomes '$dest'"
done
```

Here we're using a variable substitution to remove a trailing `.py` (if one is there to remove) and then always adding `.py` back on again. The single quotes inside the `echo` statement are not required.